# emacs +spacemacs + ess layer + julia lang - How to make working autocomplete in file

Tags: julia, ess

I installed new spacemacs version (1.03)
I added layer ess. Although documentation I seems to be only for R I tried 
working with Julia:
- I emacs, command load-ess-on-demand
- in emacs, command: ess-switch-to-ESS than I chose julia 
- than I switched current file to julia-mode

Result:
 Comapared to R:
- I don't have autocompletion in buffer of julia file. 
- In Julia repl I have completition but at not as tooltip compared to R repl.

Ask:
Could you give me advice how to make julia autocompletition working in julia buffer?

Comment: According to [ESS documentation](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/wiki/Julia#completion) you should have autocompletion in julia from version 13.09 up. What version are you using?

Comment: I use 15.09-devel version of ess

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the extra-langs configuration layer to your spacemacs configuration file.

It adds language support for 
Arduino
Julia
MATLAB
QML
OpenScad
Stan
Wolfram Language / Mathematica